# Unable to override PS1 with direnv

Tags: direnv

I am following the [direnv wiki on PS1](https://github.com/direnv/direnv/wiki/PS1). I have the following relevant entries in my files.

`.bashrc`

```
DEFAULT_PS1='\[$(ppwd)\]\u@\h:\w$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")'
# add some more things to DEFAULT_PS1, conditionally
DEFAULT_PS1+='> '

PS1=${CUSTOM_PS1:-$DEFAULT_PS1}

# optional bashrc file extensions
for f in ~/.bashrc_*; do test -s $f && . $f || true; done

eval "$(direnv hook bash)"
```

`.envrc`

```
export KUBECONFIG=~/.config/kube/homelab.yaml
export KUBE_PS1_ENABLED=on
export CUSTOM_PS1='$(kube_ps1) $ '
PATH_add scripts
```

I have allowed the latest version of the `.envrc` with `direnv allow`. However, when changing to the directory, the custom PS1 value is not set, although the values seems to be right

```
$ cd -
/home/robert/sources/oss/sling-cloud-native
direnv: loading .envrc
direnv: export +CUSTOM_PS1 +KUBE_PS1_ENABLED ~KUBECONFIG ~PATH

$ echo $PS1
\[$(ppwd)\]\u@\h:\w$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")$(kube_ps1)>

$ echo $CUSTOM_PS1
$(kube_ps1) $
```

I am not sure how the solution in the wiki is supposed to work, as apparently the value of PS1 is set to the DEFAULT_PS1 when the `.bashrc` file is loaded the first time and is not re-evaluated as part of the `direnv` hook.

How can I change the value of PS1 using `direnv`?

Answer (score 5):

The [direnv wiki](https://github.com/direnv/direnv/wiki/PS1)  mentions that the author had to "blacklist PS1 as an environment variable that can be changed," mainly because "The core issue is that PS1 is a local variable." So I don't think workarounds that involve using the `.envrc` file to indirectly modify the `PS1` can work.

I had a similar issue with python virtual environments, which I realize is different to your use case, but there is an example in [this blog](https://kellner.io/direnv.html) that could be helpful.

Because links can die I reproduce it here:

1. add the following to ~/.bashrc (me: I tested this with ~/.zshrc and it also works)

```
show_virtual_env() {
  if [[ -n "$VIRTUAL_ENV" && -n "$DIRENV_DIR" ]]; then
    echo "($(basename $VIRTUAL_ENV))"
  fi
}
export -f show_virtual_env
PS1='$(show_virtual_env)'$PS1
```

2. Then source the file again

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

The wiki also mentions adding `unset PS1` to the `.envrc` file, which removes any error about `direnv: PS1 cannot be exported...` and I can confirm that also works with this scenario.

Perhaps you can do something similar; use `.envrc` to export the environment variables as you are doing, but remove the line `export CUSTOM_PS1='$(kube_ps1) $ '` and in your `~/.bashrc` make a function that checks if you have set `KUBE_PS1_ENABLED` and appends `'$(kube_ps1) $ '` to `PS1` if it is set.

Comment: A small mention that the `unset PS1` has to be placed at the bottom of the `.envrc`